# Why does AnonymousUser returns True for is_authenticated in Django?

Tags: django

I have the following code in my view file.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    owner = request.user
    if cart.owner != owner:
        cart.owner = owner
    cart.save()
```

However I face the following error:

`Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x103ff37b8>>": "Cart.owner" must be a "User" instance.`

Why is Django running the line `cart.owner = owner` even if the user is not authenticated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is_authenticated` is a method, you're just checking to see if there is a method available with that name, not whether your user is authenticated.

You need to call the method.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
```

Comment: Shit. Thanks, newbie mistake. :)

Comment: Note that in Django 1.10, `is_authenticated` is changing from a method to an attribute, so that users don't get caught out by forgetting to call it.